# ¿Cómo acceder a variable global (lista) y modificarla desde un subproceso?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asincronismo, proceso

Tengo una `List` que necesito modificarla dentro de una `función`. Intente de dos maneras:

### **1)**

```
import multiprocessing

lista_proc = [['pruebaA','prueba A',''],
              ['pruebaB','prueba B',''],
              ['pruebaC','prueba C',''],
              ['pruebaD','prueba D',''],
              ['pruebaT','prueba T','']
             ]

def worker(proc):
    
    if os.system(f'python {proc[0]}.py') == 0: 
        print(f'{proc[1]} OK ')
        proc[2]='OK'
    else:
        print(f'{proc[1]} ERROR ')
        proc[2],'ERROR'
    
        
for item in lista_proc:
    thread = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(item,))
    thread.start()


>prueba A ERROR 
>prueba B OK 
>prueba D ERROR 
>prueba C ERROR 
>prueba T OK 

lista_proc
```

output:

```
 >>[['pruebaA', 'prueba A', ''],
 >>['pruebaB', 'prueba B', ''],
 >>['pruebaC', 'prueba C', ''],
 >>['pruebaD', 'prueba D', ''],
 >>['pruebaT', 'prueba T', '']]
```

---

## 2)

```
import multiprocessing
#start_ = datetime.datetime.today()
lista = []
def worker(proc,lista_aux):
    
    if os.system(f'python {proc[0]}.py') == 0: 
        print(f'{proc[1]} OK ')
        lista_aux.append([proc[0],'OK'])
    else:
        print(f'{proc[1]} ERROR ')
        lista_aux.append([proc[0],'ERROR'])
    
        
for item in lista_proc:
    thread = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(item,lista,))
    thread.start()

lista
>>[]
```

Por lo que sospecho es que bueno.. hace falta un `return lista` por ejemplo, en la opción 2, pero al usar `multiprocessing`, no sabría como obtenerlo del otro lado ya que hago `thread =`. Me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de solucionar ese problema.

*La idea del script es que al terminar el `loop` cuando haga `lista_proc`
muestre:*

```
 [['pruebaA','prueba A','ERROR'],
  ['pruebaB','prueba B','OK'],
  ['pruebaC','prueba C','ERROR'],
  ['pruebaD','prueba D','ERROR'],
  ['pruebaT','prueba T','OK']
  ]
```

Comment: para cosas como esta existe [redis](https://redis.io/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voy a contestar primero dando una solución en base a tu implementación actual, no obstante al final de la respuesta doy la forma de hacer lo que pretendes usando `subprocess` directamente, si necesidad de crear un proceso intermedio, una forma mucho más eficiente, directa y simple.

Cuando se crea un proceso hijo  tu lista se serializa vía pickle antes de pasarla al nuevo proceso. Esto significa que **cada proceso tiene de inicio una copia de la lista  que tiene tu proceso padre, pero  son objetos totalmente distintos, localizados en distintas partes de la memoria.  Modificar la lista en un proceso no altera en absoluto la lista del proceso padre o de los otros procesos hijos**. Ten en cuenta que aún usando forking (sistemas *nix) para implementar el proceso, las variables globales no se comparten entre procesos, los procesos empiezan con el mismo estado inicial que el padre, pero a partir de ahí se bifurcan y no comparten memoria entre ellos (a no ser que explícitamente usemos algún mecanismo para compartir memoria, como `multiprocessing.Array`/ctypes)

Lo que puedes hacer es usar memoria compartida mediante `multiprocessing.Manager`:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import os



def worker(proc, result):
    if os.system(f'python {proc[0]}.py') == 0: 
        proc[2] = 'OK'
    else:
        proc[2] = 'ERROR'
    result.append(proc)


lista_proc = [['pruebaA','prueba A',''],
              ['pruebaB','prueba B',''],
              ['pruebaC','prueba C',''],
              ['pruebaD','prueba D',''],
              ['pruebaT','prueba T','']
             ]


if __name__ == '__main__':

    with Manager() as manager:
        result = manager.list()
        prs = [Process(target=worker, args=(proc,result))for proc in lista_proc]

        for pr in prs:
            pr.start()
        for pr in prs:
            pr.join()

        print(result)
```

Otra opción es crear un  piscina de procesos (`multiprocessing.Pool`) y que vayan consumiendo de forma ordenada las sublistas de `lista_proc`, la modifiquen y  la retornen:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os

def worker(proc):
    if os.system(f'python {proc[0]}.py') == 0: 
        proc[2] = 'OK'
    else:
        proc[2] = 'ERROR'
    return proc


lista_proc = [['pruebaA','prueba A',''],
              ['pruebaB','prueba B',''],
              ['pruebaC','prueba C',''],
              ['pruebaD','prueba D',''],
              ['pruebaT','prueba T','']
             ]


if __name__ == '__main__':

    with Pool(processes=len(lista_proc)) as pool:
        res = pool.map_async(worker, lista_proc)
        lista_proc = res.get()
    print(lista_proc)
```

---

Aunque lo anterior funciona, estás creando un proceso hijo que a su vez lanza un subproceso. Puedes simplemente pasar de `os.system` (API prácticamente considerada como anticuada) y usar `subprocess.Popen` directamente para lanzar los script Python. Mediante `wait` esperas a que cada proceso termine y obtienes su código de retorno. No tienes que compartir nada entre procesos ni crear copias de la lista, ya que es el proceso padre el que finalmente modifica la lista.

```
import subprocess



lista_proc = [['pruebaA','prueba A',''],
              ['pruebaB','prueba B',''],
              ['pruebaC','prueba C',''],
              ['pruebaD','prueba D',''],
              ['pruebaT','prueba T','']
             ]


procesos = [subprocess.Popen(("python", f"{proc[0]}.py")) for proc in lista_proc]

for proc, proceso in zip(lista_proc, procesos):
    proc[2] = "OK" if proceso.wait() == 0 else "ERROR"

print(lista_proc)
```